# How to match comments starting with # but not hexadecimal colors

Tags: regex

I can't figure out how to match comments but not HTML hex in regex. For example I want the script to match

```
#I'm a comment, yes I am
```

but not

```
#FF33AF
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Write some kind of parser?

Comment: Normally the pattern: #comment will just display "#comment" in the browser. An HTML comment looks like: <!-- comment -->

Comment: What kind of document has *script-like* comments, and *CSS-like* color codes? Of course, you can *create* one, but it must be an unusual occurence?

Comment: Tcl and Python programs both have script-like comments and CSS-like color codes. Using #rrggbb came along waaaaaaay before CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead. From the python documentation:

*(?!...)*

*Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?!Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s not followed by 'Asimov'.*

Comment: Perfect! I have found this bit of code before but all documentation of it I found were horrible examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To do the job right you need a parser not a regular expression matcher. For example, is "#decade" a comment or a color name? You can't know without a little context.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious regex is going to be something like:

```
(?m-:^\s*#(?![0-9A-Fa-f]{6}).*$)
```

This gives you all lines that start with a '#'.  From your post your not very specific but I think that is what your looking for.

Updated:

Corrected to only allow the six:

```
(?m-:^\s*#(?![0-9A-Za-z]{6}\s*$).*$)
```